# Watches in Curator not getting triggered after resetting it on Expiry

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I have a basepath which has multiple children.I am adding watchers on the basepath and all children on startup of the application.

```
void init(){
                List<String> children = zkCfg.getClient().getChildren().usingWatcher(this).forPath(basePath);
                Stat stat = zkCfg.getClient().checkExists().usingWatcher(this).forPath(basePath);
                lastKnownVersion.put(basePath.substring(basePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1), stat.getVersion());
                for (String child : children) {
                    stat = zkCfg.getClient().checkExists().usingWatcher(this).forPath(basePath + "/" + child);
                    lastKnownVersion.put(child, stat.getVersion());
                }
}
```

Now, I am catching the expired Event in process method.

```
public void process(WatchedEvent event) {

        try {    
            synchronized (this) {   
                if (event.getState().equals(Event.KeeperState.Expired)) {           
                  init()  
                }
}
```

This method gets executed on expiry, but the watches don't get triggered on any changes in node.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a solution by myself.

Instead, of managing watchers on a node and all its child node by myself.Used Treecache, it manages all your watchers on session expiry also.